# add link/image of ckeditor doesn't work when its inside a colorbox

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, colorbox

I am using latest version of colorbox and ckeditor in my project. I am using ckeditor in colorbox so everything looks good. Now, when I try to add link, its opening popup but I am not able click on textbox or dropdown in it.

I have already seen there are people who faces same issues but all those issues are a year or two old so please let me know solution if anyone knows.

Comment: Is your dropdown decorated somehow or is it a simple select control?

Comment: @Omri, Its simple select control, default one by ckeditor. http://ckeditor.com/demo